# I have trouble understanding about blocks of for loop and if statement

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, block, c99

In C Primer Plus, the author says that

> A C99 feature, mentioned earlier, is that statements that are part of
>   a loop or if statement qualify as a block even if braces (that is, { }
>   ) aren’t used. More completely, an entire loop is a sub-block to the
>   block containing it, and the loop body is a sub-block to the entire
>   loop block.

I guess the **loop body** means the `printf(...)` statement in the example below. But what do these these two bold words mean? : ".. an **entire loop** is a sub-block to **the block** containing it,..." It would be nice if you could explain it using the example below!

```
for(int n =1;n<3;n++)
    printf("%d \n",n);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C11 standard says, in §6.8.5 **Iteration statements**

> ¶5 An iteration statement is a block whose scope is a strict subset of the scope of its
>   enclosing block. The loop body is also a block whose scope is a strict subset of the scope
>   of the iteration statement.

I think this is what the statement you quote is attempting to paraphrase.

What this is driving at, somewhat opaquely (welcome to the world of reading standards), is that an iteration statement (`while` loop, `do … while` loop or `for` loop) is treated as a block.  This primarily affects the `for` loop with variable declarations.

Consider:

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    printf(" %d", i);
putchar('\n');
```

The wording means that the code functions as if you had:

```
{
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d", i);
    }
}
putchar('\n');
```

This particularly limits the scope of `i` to the `for` loop; it is not accessible outside the loop.  The loop body being a block whose scope is a strict subset of the iteration statement isn't a big surprise.  The surrounding block is less obvious and could be a surprise.

Answer (score 4):

It is phrased a bit badly, but it's quite simple:

```
for(int n =1;n<3;n++)      // <-- loop
    printf("%d \n",n);     // <-- block
```

The loop body is as you said the `printf()` in this case, and in general, trying to keep my answer as minimum as possible, this is the format:

```
for(...; ....;)
    body_of_loop
```

---

The *sub* comes into play when you have nested loops, or if statements. For example, a double for loop:

```
1. for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)         
2.    for(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)    
3.        printf("hi\n");
```

> More completely, an entire loop is a sub-block to the block containing it, and the loop body is a sub-block to the entire loop block.

So, line 2 is an *entire loop* and it's a sub-block to the *block* that it is part of. The block of the exterior for loop is lines 2 and 3.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a code block, for example:

```
while(1)                 <-- code block (contains if [that contains printf])
    if(2)                <-- sub block (contains printf)
       printf("3");      <--- part of if block
```

the printf is considered to be a part of the if block, and the if block itself (now containing the printf as well) is considered a part of the bigger while block. This could go on and on...

```
while(1)
  while(2)
    if(3)
      for(;;)
        i++;
```

Each of the 3 mid-lines here is a sub block that contains following lines